# SQLAlchemy Core inserts make (Pyramid) scoped session hanging

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, pyramid, pylons

I have lots of child objects to add to a parent SQA object, sometimes 10,000 or so. The code runs in Pyramid app, which makes use of scoped session and `ZopeTransactionExtension`:

```
DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension()))
```

This works without a problem:

```
lines = [{'col1':1, 'col2':2, 'related_id':1}, ...]
for d in lines:
    d['related_id'] = related_id
    f = SQAObject(**d)
    DBSession.add(f)
```

For performance I rewrote this using SQLAlchemy Core `insert`s:

```
lines = [{'col1':1, 'col2':2, 'related_id':1}, ...]
rbrf_table = SQAObject.__table__
eng = DBSession.get_bind()
conn = eng.connect()
for d in lines:
    d['related_id'] = related_id
conn.execute(rbrf_table.insert().values(lines))
conn.close()
eng.dispose()
```

This causes a rather weird problem: the code executes (faster), but after HTTP request is finished, the result is not returned to HTTP client. Instead the Python process keeps consuming 100% CPU indefinitely (I waited half an hour to make sure if it completes in any time).

I checked Postgres locks to make sure they do not block it as well as activity (`select * from pg_stat_activity`), but there does not seem to be anything unusual.

What might be the cause of this problem?

P.S. Suspecting that disposing an engine might cause this problem, I've ran the same code with and without `eng.dispose()`, with the same result.

*UPDATE*

The plot thickens. If I execute individual inserts instead, it works:

```
rbrf_table = RTABomRowFile.__table__
eng = DBSession.get_bind()
conn = eng.connect()
for d in lines:
    ...
    ins = rbrf_table.insert().values(d)
    conn.execute(ins)
conn.execute('COMMIT')
conn.close()
eng.dispose()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, it's `.values(list_of_dictionaries)` call that causes the problem. This works:

```
eng = DBSession.get_bind()
eng.execute(rbrf_table.insert(), lines)
eng.dispose()
```